# inspect jQuery object in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, safari, webkit, console.log

I know this question has been asked over and over again, and answers to those questions aren't really helping me out as they are all different.

I need to inspect the properties of a jQuery object in console. They keep changing this and it's getting annoying now.

In Safari, console treats a jQuery object as an Array, when it's prototype is an Object, and it has other properties than simple array keys and a length.

Is there any way to persuade Safari (and webkit in general) to display the jQuery object as an actual object?

Comment: Did you try using `console.dir(obj);`?

Comment: Well I never knew about that one. I knew about `log` and `error` but not `dir`

Comment: Just read about it, yes that is what I need. Shame that the console doesn't use this by default. If you answer with this, I will select it as correct.

Comment: Or use JSON.stringify(obj);